# How to remove vertical space between tables

Tags: html, html-table

I have a PHP page which outputs a menu inside a table. Below it there is another table containing (dutch) text.

Whats driving me nuts here, is that IE10 and Firefox and Chrome, all add two empty rows between them like if I typed `<br>` worse Firefox code inspector actually shows it as `<br><br />`
But when asking for page source with firefox, it isnt there at all.

The page and the source I temporally placed [here](http://www.stapelen.info/Web/Sapec/index.php)
Even if I remove images from the page, I still have this problem.
But as if by magic, the contact page..does not show this problem.

Its not related to padding, I already tested that that for inner html cell distance, so text is a bit of the border. I even added style to use noborder no effect either.

Comment: You should only use tables for tabular data, not for design. Use div's instead.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: It sounds like your page is being interpreted as invalid for some reason, causing the browsers to drop to compatible mode. Try running it through e.g. the W3C validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, and i am posting it so others might find it helpfully too.

The problem in my page was that although there was no space line break between the table elements; as it was written like :

```
<table>
<tr><td>..some  cells stuff .. </td></tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr><td>..some  cells stuff .. </td></tr>
</table>
```

The problem rather was that in the lower table there where 
 tags not enclosed inside table  elements, something like :

```
<table>
<tr><td>..some  cells stuff .. </td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>..some  cells stuff .. </td></tr> <br><br>
</table>
```

Now firefox did reported that there was something in the tag Tbody, but tbody isnt a 'real' tag, i looked it up, its firefox way of saying i know tables and what you wrote inside that table body that isn't what i understand as part of a normal table layout columns and rows. Its a bit confusing but thanks for @luaan for pointing me to do some validation tests.
Because well its still a bit bizarre that those break lines declared much later in the page caused havoc before the bottom table.. but then again it was wrong code i shouldn't have written it like that.